# Change JSON to following format in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How do I change JSON of following format in javascript

```
data = [{acquired: "2018-03-09T22:49:52.935Z", mean_ndvi: -0.0483685}
{acquired: "2018-02-13T22:49:16.568Z", mean_ndvi: 0.00595065}
{acquired: "2018-04-01T22:50:30.912Z", mean_ndvi: -0.033455}]
```

to exactly

```
data = {"2018-03-09T22:49:52.935Z":-0.0483685, "2018-02-13T22:49:16.568Z": 0.00595065, "2018-04-01T22:50:30.912Z": -0.033455}
```

My attempt.

```
var json =data; var obj2 ={}; var obj3 =[]; 
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) 
{ var obj = json[i]; 
obj2 = {[obj.acquired]:obj.mean_ndvi};
obj3.push(obj2); } 
console.log(obj3);
```

I'm able to get it in the following format.

```
 {2018-04-01T22:50:30.912Z: -0.033455}, 
 {2018-04-01T22:50:30.912Z: -0.033455}, 
 {2018-04-01T22:50:30.912Z: -0.033455}
```

Please check what changes can be made to get the result in one row.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes I did, I'm able to get it this format.
{2018-04-01T22:50:30.912Z: -0.033455},
{2018-04-01T22:50:30.912Z: -0.033455},
{2018-04-01T22:50:30.912Z: -0.033455}

Comment: If you want the answer I could tell you : `var obj = {};for(d of data) obj[d.acquired] = d.mean_ndvi;`, but this question you'd better try it yourself.

Comment: Please add solution to this specific problem. I'm stuck here for a long time. I've tried a lot.

Comment: Use simple array iterate, and get every item's value, and then set to the object you want. Try to give this question a solution and try to solve it. If you block when you try to solve, we'll be glad to help you.

Comment: var json =data; var obj2 ={};
var obj3 =[];


for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i];
   obj2 = {[obj.acquired]:obj.mean_ndvi}
    obj3.push(obj2);
}
console.log(obj3);

Comment: Solved it.
                        var json = data;
   var obj_0 = {};
   for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
       var obj = json[i];
    obj_0[obj.acquired] = obj.mean_ndvi;
   }
   data= obj_0;  
Thank you @Terry Wei

Comment: You're welcome. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows (with some [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) mixed in):

```
data.reduce((a, {acquired, mean_ndvi}) => ({[acquired]: mean_ndvi, ...a}), {});
```

Full snippet:

```js
const data = [
    {acquired: "2018-03-09T22:49:52.935Z", mean_ndvi: -0.0483685},
    {acquired: "2018-02-13T22:49:16.568Z", mean_ndvi: 0.00595065},
    {acquired: "2018-04-01T22:50:30.912Z", mean_ndvi: -0.033455}
];

const result = data.reduce((a, {acquired, mean_ndvi}) => ({[acquired]: mean_ndvi, ...a}), {});

console.log(result);
```